# How to Populate Auto Suppression List from Cloudpage Form

Tags: cloudpage, autosuppressionlist

I am trying to create a cloud page form with just one field (Email), I would like to add that email to Auto suppression list when I submit the cloud page form.

I created a cloud page with smart capture function which now adds the email into a data extension, can someone advise me on how I can get the form data into the Auto suppression list either by using the data extension or without the DE.

Since the cloud page already submits the data into a DE, I am now thinking if there's a way to use the automation studio to fetch the data from this DE and add to the Auto suppression list using a query.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? 
Any help here would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in both the ways (directly into auto-suppression list or from data extension to auto suppression list)

*Cloud Page > Auto suppression list:*

You can use the below SSJS script to add it in the cloud page:

```
<script runat="server">
var insertRow = Platform.Function.InsertData('Auto-supression list name',['Email Address'],['sample@example.com']);
</script>
```

*Cloud page > Data Extension > Auto suppression list:*

You can create an automation with the below activities and schedule it:

- Data extract activity - You can use the data extension extract to extract the data extension records
- File Transfer activity - You can use this to move the file from
  safehouse to marketing cloud SFTP
- Import activity - Use this activity to import the records into
  auto-suppression list

Let me know if this helps.